# How to control caching in django template view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a method in view which loads the statistics page.

Here I need to control caching of '@csrf_protect' from the view.

My code snippet looks like -

```
def statistics(request, id):
    test = Test.objects.get(id=id)
    result = statistics.objects.get(test=test, user=request.user)

    context ={ 'test' : test, 'result' : result, 'review' : True  }
    return render_to_response('statistics.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @cache_page is a method decorator.

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
def statistics(request, id):
    test = Test.objects.get(id=id)
    result = statistics.objects.get(test=test, user=request.user)

    context ={ 'test' : test, 'result' : result, 'review' : True  }
    return render_to_response('statistics.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```